# Difference in commands to create executables from shared library

Tags: c, gcc, shared-libraries

What is the difference between the launch and launch1 executable created by the following 
commands:

```
gcc main.o ./my_lib/libshared_secure.so -o launch
```

and

```
gcc main.o -L ./my_lib -lshared_secure -o launch1
```

Here main.o is the object code of the main function and libshared_secure.so is a shared 
library. I expected that both launch and launch1 would be same but I was incorrect. Why 
are the two executables different and which part of the above commands causes these 
differences?
The difference was that in executing launch I didn't have to set and export LD_LIBRARY_PATH variable to the path of libshared_secure.so but I had to do that in executing launch1.

Comment: you can run `file launch` and `file launch1`

Answer (score 2):

```
readelf -d launch | grep libshared_secure.so
```

Will report `[./my_lib/libshared_secure.so]`. However, for `launch1` it will be `[libshared_secure.so]`. Linker will try to load given libraries in system directories and in directories relative to your current working directory (so, if you'll launch binary from some other place (not `./launch` but e.g. `../launch` from subdirectory) - it will not find library without `LD_LIBRARY_PATH`).

Other functionality is rpath - linker could take directory to look into, and write it into ELF header, without need to specify LD_LIBRARY_PATH. This avoids problem with current working directory because you could use paths relative to binary directory, not your current one. E.g. `gcc -Wl,-rpath='$ORIGIN/my_lib' -Lmy_lib -lshared_secure main.o` will link your binary with `libshared_secure.so` but will add relative entry to `rpath`.